# Primefaces 5.3 calendar disappeared after update with chart

Tags: ajax, events, charts, primefaces, calendar

I'm trying to get data between 2 dates with chart everything works fin but when I'm using Ajax update the second date disappeared there is my code

```
<p:calendar value="#{bean.date}">
<p:ajax event=”dateSelect” listener=”#{bean.handleDateSelect}” update=”dateEnd” />
 </p:calendar>
<p:calendar id="dateEnd" value="#{calendarBean.date2}"
mindate="#{bean.date}"></p:calendar> 
<p:chart type="pie" model="#{bean.model}" />
```

if I remove the Ajax it works but I need it for mindate.

Comment: If you update the second calendar what you see is the value stored server-side, so since you aren't processing all changes of it you lose that value. Try to add an ajax to the second calendar, with `process="@this"` and pay attention, in `handleDateSelect`, to manage all scenario, according the `mindate` check. Read this [BalusC Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes) for more info.

Comment: I'm talking about disappearing of calendar the second one disappeare completely from my page

Comment: Ok, always or sometimes? Have you checked for error / raised log level (try with f5, the page should break, and don't use production as the stage if you want to see this kind of error)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got to solve the problem,so I have to init the chartSerie for exemple :

```
ChartSeries serie = new ChartSeries();

for (Object o : list
        ) {
            serie.set(o.getLabel(), o.getValue());
        }
// This line what i was missing
if (serie.size() == 0)
            serie.set(0, 0);
```